# Why residual current device doesn't trip

Tags: ground

I bought a residual current device to my home workshop for safety and I was testing it .I connected it to workshop's power cable and for test I used 4.7k ohm resistor .device rated for 30mA (220v) and I connect to resistor between live wire and ground .It tripped as soon as I connect it , no problem in here .Then I add 14V transformer to the plug and this time I used 220 ohm resistor but nothing happened .I used my multimeter for current values and even I remove the resistor between live and ground no current flow.Why the transformer changes how the ground work ?

Comment: Draw the circuit please.

Comment: I'm sorry , I can't draw the circuit because I'm using mobile right now but @duskwuff's circuit explains my question's circuit

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no path for current to flow through the resistor.

The secondary windings of the transformer are isolated from the primary (and, hence, from ground as well). Connecting a resistor between one terminal and ground doesn't form a closed circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5jGjAm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: So when I connect between live wire and ground , circuit conducts between city's power transformer and earth ?

Comment: But I heard people electrocuted because of high voltage transformer's .In this logic you can't electrocuted as long as you use a second transformer

Comment: Right, to the extent that there is only a SINGLE fault downstream of that transformer (Which is hard to guarantee at scale). There are systems that use an isolating transformer together with monitoring electronics that will alarm on a fault to earth (but let the power stay on), somewhat popular in hospital operating and ICU environments where the risk of a second fault before you can get someone to fix the first one is less then the risk of a sudden power outage.

Comment: I'm sorry , I went to holiday and my internet won't work there .I read your comment but I don't understand it (I understand what you said but I don't know how it answers my question